# Computer won't boot - related to KB4056892 (Meltdown) update?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, meltdown

My computer has been doing strange and random things for the last year and I think it may have with a hardware problem I cannot find.

However, on this occasion suddenly my computer wouldn't boot: after the BIOS I would get a black window with a blinking underscore. I could only start my Windows system manually forcing the computer to start from the main HDD.

The problem seemed to be random when starting the computer but now I believe this is what happened: it would only happen when really starting Windows, but it didn't appear when I was just returning from sleeping mode and/or hibernation.

This happened to me after installing KB4056892 Windows Update. I think this update is related to Meltdown vulnerability in Intel processors (which of course I am using as any home user). Do you believe this update could have changed my bios booting configuration?

Comment: Intel or AMD.  Edit your question

Comment: “Do you believe this update could have changed my bios booting configuration?” - No.  you either have an AV that’s incompatible with the update or you have incompatible and hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound Intel. I think it is already stated in the question ("Intel processors (which of course I am using ...").

Comment: @Ramhound But changing the boot options in the bios configuration solved the problem. It doesn't seem like an antivirus problem, as it appears to only have affected the bios configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For the known issue, you can refer to the detailed description here:

Microsoft has reports of some customers with AMD devices getting into an unbootable state after installing this KB. To prevent this issue, Microsoft will temporarily pause Windows OS updates to devices with impacted AMD processors at this time.

Microsoft is working with AMD to resolve this issue and resume Windows OS security updates to the affected AMD devices via Windows Update and WSUS as soon as possible. If you have experienced an unbootable state or for more information see KB4073707. For AMD specific information please contact AMD.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4073707/windows-os-security-update-block-for-some-amd-based-devices

**Edit 1:**

Installing S&M microcode updates on computers with Intel Haswell and Broadwell processors

a.  Intel security update: [Addressing reboot issues](https://newsroom.intel.com/news/intel-security-issue-update-addressing-reboot-issues/)

b.  Computerworld: [Intel says new firmware patches trigger reboots in Haswell and Broadwell systems](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3247788/intel-says-new-firmware-patches-trigger-reboots-in-haswell-and-broadwell-systems.html)

Also, Standalone hotfixes released to address AMD issue (and know other known issues) so far:

Win10 1709: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4073290/unbootable-state-for-amd-devices-in-windows-10-version-1709

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft is reporting a problem with AMD processors. Therefore, I understand there is no problem with the update on Intel processors as mine.

Comment: Unexpected issue can also be caused by install incompatible AV software. And also Intel has such issue.